# Помогите с mysql запросом выборки из 3-х таблиц

Tags: mysql

Добрый день!
За последние 7 лет работы так привык к фреймворковскому функционалу для работы с базой, что вообще разучился писать запросы на sql(
В общем, у меня есть 3 таблицы:

**1: regions:**

[image: regions]

**2: cities:**

[image: cities]

**3: organizations:**
В этой таблице куча полей, но, в данном случае, меня интересуют поля: region_id и city_id

Мне необходимо написать запрос, который бы выводил все города, но только из региона, id которого хранится в поле region_id таблицы organizations.

Запрос у меня получился следующий:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name FROM cities c, regions r, organizations org WHERE c.region_id=r.id AND r.id=org.region_id
```

Запрос возвращает города правильно (города, которые находятся в других регионах в вывод не попадают), но из базы возвращаются 3500 строк при том, что в списке у меня всего 7 городов.... Список из городов дублируется множество раз...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Элементарная задача... Ввела меня в такой ступор....
Подскажите, плиз, в чём проблема..

Comment: Количество строк у вас видимо по количеству организаций. или select distinct или как уже ответили ниже, `region_id IN(select ...)`

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT c.id, c.name 
FROM cities c, regions r, organizations org 
WHERE c.region_id=r.id 
    AND r.id=org.region_id
    AND r.id=c.region_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Лишнее умножение таблиц.
Правильно примерно так:

```
select c.id, c.name from cities c
where c.region_id in (select r.id from regions r, organizations org where r.id=org.region_id)
```

Comment: Практически так, только таблица regions в запросе вообще не нужна, т.к. требуемый ID уже есть в organization :)